# How exactly does the .any() Python method work?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement, any

I'm trying to write a script that simulates a system of chemical reactions over time. One of the inputs to the function is the following array:

```
popul_num = np.array([200, 100, 0, 0])
```

Which contains the number of discrete molecules of each species in the system. Part of the main function has an `if` statement that's meant to check that number of molecules is positive. `if` it is processed to the next iteration, `else` break out of the whole simulation

```
if popul_num.any() < 0: # Any method isn't working! --> Does .any() work on arrays or just lists? 
        print("Break out of loop negative molecule numbers")
        tao_all = tao_all[0:-1]
        popul_num_all = popul_num_all[0:-1]       
    else:
        break
```

I've used the `.any()` to try find if any element of the `popul_num` array is negative. But it doesn't work, it doesn't throw an error, the system just never enters the if statement and I can't figure out why?

I've just ran the program and the final number of molecules the system returned was: `[135 -19  65  54]` the program should have broken out before the second element got to -19.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: any will return True when at least one of the elements is True; `any(iterable)`

Comment: Just do `if np.any(popul_num < 0): # do_stuff` or `if (popul_num < 0).any(): #do_stuff`. You start by constructing a boolean array _before_ applying `any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `any` method of numpy arrays returns a boolean value, so when you write:

```
if popul_num.any() < 0:
```

`popul_num.any()` will be either `True` (=1) or `False` (=0) so it will never be less than zero. Thus, you will never enter this if-statement.

What `any()` does is evaluate each element of the array as a boolean and return whether *any* of them are truthy. For example:

```
>>> np.array([0.0]).any()
False

>>> np.array([1.0]).any()
True

>>> np.array([0.0, 0.35]).any()
True
```

As you can see, Python/numpy considers 0 to be falsy and all other numbers to be truthy. So calling `any` on an array of numbers tells us whether any number in the array is nonzero. But you want to know whether any number is *negative*, so we have to transfrom the array first. Let's introduce a negative number into your array to demonstrate.

```
>>> popul_num = np.array([200, 100, 0, -1])
>>> popul_num < 0  # Test is applied to all elements in the array
np.ndarray([False, False, False, True])
>>> (popul_num < 0).any()
True
```

---

You asked about `any` on lists versus arrays. Python's builtin [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) has no `any` method:

```
>>> [].any()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'any'
```

There is a builtin *function* (not method since it doesn't belong to a class) called [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) that serves the same purpose as the numpy `.any` method. These two expressions are logically equivalent:

```
any(popul_num < 0)

(popul_num < 0).any()
```

We would generally expect the second one to be faster since numpy is implemented in C. However only the first one will work with non-numpy types such as `list` and `set`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.any()` on a boolean array *after* doing the comparison, not on the values of `popul_num` themselves.  It will return `True` if any of the values of the boolean array are `True`, otherwise `False`.

In fact, `.any()` tests for any "[truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)" values, which for integers means non-zero values, so it will work on an array of integers to test if any of them are non-zero, which is what you are doing, but this is not testing the thing that you are interested in knowing.  The code then compounds the problem by doing an `< 0` test on the boolean value returned by `any`, which always evaluates `True` because boolean values are treated as `0` and `1` (for `False` and `True` respectively) in operations involving integers.

You can do:

```
if (popul_num < 0).any():
    do_whatever
```

Here `popul_num < 0` is a boolean array containing the results of element-by-element comparisons.  In your example:

```
>>> popul_num < 0
array([False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

You are, however, correct to use `array.any()` (or `np.any(array)`) rather than using the builtin `any()`.  The latter happens to work for a 1-d array, but would not work with more dimensions.  This is because iterating e.g. over a 4d array (which is what the builtin `any()` would do) gives a sequence of 3d arrays, not the individual elements.

There is also similarly `.all()`.  The above test is equivalent to:

```
if not (popul_num >= 0).all():
```

Answer (score 1):

`any()` is a method for use on iterables.  It returns `True` if any of the items in the iterable are truthy.  You want something more like:

```
if any([True for x in popul_num if x > 0]):
  print("at least one element was greater than zero!")
```

Answer (score 0):

**any()** returns *True*, if at least one of the elements is *True*:

```py
L1 = [False, False, False]
any(L1)
# >>> False

L1 = [True, False, False]
any(L1)
# >>> True

L1 = ["Hi", False, False]
any(L1)
# >>> True

L1 = []
any(L1)
# >>> False
```

Answer (score 0):

any() returns True if at least one element in a NumPy array evaluates to True and np.all test whether all array elements along a given axis evaluate to True. What you need to solve your problem is the all method.